# .innerHTML doesn't print anything out inside div's

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in html and javascript. I am trying to output some text when a button is pressed, from javascript using .innerHTML but it doesn't print anything out. I am linking the div's by id(if it is possible I would like to avoid loops). Here's the code;

```
<section class="box special features">
<div class="features-row">
<section>
        <h3 ="h31">&nbsp;</h3>  
        <p id="p1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="p2">&nbsp;</p>
</section>
<section id="s2">
    <h3 id="h32">&nbsp;</h3>
    <p id="p3">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="p4">&nbsp;</p>
</section>
</div>
</section>
<button onclick= "myFunction()" id="button" name="button">ok</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction () {
   h31.innerHTML = ("some text 1");
   p1.innerHTML = ("some text 2");
   p2.innerHTML = ("some text 3");
   h32.innerHTML = ("some text 4");
   p3.innerHTML = ("some text 5");
   p4.innerHTML = ("some text 4");
   }
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `document.getElementById()`

Comment: h31, p1, p2.... are undefinned since you declare them ;) like `var h31 = document.getElementById('h31');`

Comment: Most browsers allow to access elements as members of the `window` object by their id, so on the surface this should work. On the other hand, is the `<h3 ="h31">` typo present in your actual code?

Comment: @Yoplaboom thank you !

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> <h3 ="h31">&nbsp;</h3>
> ```

You missed the attribute name for the `id` attribute here.

Consequently, `h31.innerHTML = ("some text 1");`  errors and the function aborts.

```html
<section class="box special features">
<div class="features-row">
<section>
        <h3 id="h31">&nbsp;</h3>  
        <p id="p1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="p2">&nbsp;</p>
</section>
<section id="s2">
    <h3 id="h32">&nbsp;</h3>
    <p id="p3">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="p4">&nbsp;</p>
</section>
</div>
</section>
<button onclick= "myFunction()" id="button" name="button">ok</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction () {
   h31.innerHTML = ("some text 1");
   p1.innerHTML = ("some text 2");
   p2.innerHTML = ("some text 3");
   h32.innerHTML = ("some text 4");
   p3.innerHTML = ("some text 5");
   p4.innerHTML = ("some text 4");
   }
</script>
```

This would have been picked up if you had used a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Note, it is considered best practise to use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or another DOM method rather than depending on the non-obvious behaviour of browsers inflating any element with an `id` into a global JS variable.

Comment: Also, of course the `myFunction()` function is defined but not invoked.  It will need to be invoked somewhere before the user will actualy see the text added to these elements.

Comment: @CarlFink — from the question: `<button onclick= "myFunction()"`

Comment: D'oh!  Reading comprehension fail.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score -1):

`h31` and your other identifiers aren't defined.  You need to actually get the HTML elements by doing something like:

`document.getElementById("h31").innerHTML = "some text 1";`

Comment: That isn't true. Using `getElementById` (note case! JavaScript is case sensitive!) is best practise, but that isn't the actual problem here. That change won't fix the problem because there is no element with the id `h31` in the code in the question.

Comment: The creation of a global variable matching the ID of an element is new to me, but I just tried it, and indeed it works!  Thank you for the information.